# Using cuBLAS in OpenAcc

Tags: cublas, openacc, pgi, cblas

I want to replace the call to "cblas_dgemm()" with cublasDgemm(). Here is the original wrapper from Shark machine learning library:

```
inline void gemm(
    CBLAS_ORDER const Order, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB,
    int M, int N, int K,
    double alpha, double const *A, int lda,
    double const *B, int ldb,
    double beta, double *C, int ldc
){

    cblas_dgemm(
        Order, TransA, TransB,
        M, N, K,
        alpha, 
        A, lda,
        B, ldb,
        beta, 
        C, ldc
    );

}
```

And here is the modified code using OpenAcc pragmas:

```
inline void gemm(
    CBLAS_ORDER const Order, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB,
    int M, int N, int K,
    double alpha, double const *A, int lda,
    double const *B, int ldb,
    double beta, double *C, int ldc
){
        #ifdef _OPENACC
        cublasOperation_t OpT_A, OpT_B; 
            switch (TransA)
        {
            case CblasNoTrans:
                OpT_A = CUBLAS_OP_N;
                break;
            case CblasTrans:
                OpT_A = CUBLAS_OP_T;
                break;
            case CblasConjTrans:
                OpT_A = CUBLAS_OP_C;
                break;
            default:
                                OpT_A = CUBLAS_OP_N;
        }
               switch (TransB)
                {
                        case CblasNoTrans:
                                OpT_B = CUBLAS_OP_N;
                break;
                        case CblasTrans:
                                OpT_B = CUBLAS_OP_T;
                break;
                        case CblasConjTrans:
                                OpT_B = CUBLAS_OP_C;
                break;
                        default:
                                OpT_B = CUBLAS_OP_N;
                }

              cublasHandle_t handle;
              #pragma acc data copyin(OpT_A, OpT_B, M, N, K, alpha, A[0:M][0:K], lda, B[0:K][0:N], ldb, beta, ldc) copy(C[0:M][0:N])
                      {
                                 #pragma acc host_data use_device(handle,OpT_A, OpT_B, A, B, C, M, N, K, lda, ldb, ldc, alpha, beta)
                                 {
                                     cublasDgemm(handle,OpT_A,OpT_B,M,N,K,&alpha,A,lda,B,ldb,&beta,C,ldc);
                                }
                        }

    #else

    cblas_dgemm(
        Order, TransA, TransB,
        M, N, K,
        alpha, 
        A, lda,
        B, ldb,
        beta, 
        C, ldc
    );
    #endif
}
```

The problem is when I compile the code with OpenAcc flag, the elements of the result matrix, i.e. C, are all zeros before and after the kernel execution. I am not sure what I am missing here. 
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the basic structure right. You don't need any of the scalar variables on the `data` or `host_data` directives though. That's the Op*, M, N, K, and ld* variables. I think this is likely your issue, as cublasDgemm will try to resolve those variables on the host in order to launch the kernel.